# C#(WCF) - Create excel file in network shared drive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, oledb, wcf-data-services

My visual studio project is stored in `C:\Projects` and project name is `Project1`, file name is `Test.xls`

```
string directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
// directory = C:\\Projects\\Project1 (local drive)

directory = directory.Remove(0, 2);
// directory = \\Projects\\Project1

string newDirectory = "\\server" + directory; 
// newDirectory = \\server\\Projects\\Project1 (now, network shared drive)

string pathCreate = System.IO.Path.Combine(newDirectory, file);
// pathCreate = \\server\\Projects\\Project1\\Test.xls
string excelConStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + pathCreate + @"; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"";";

private void CreateExcel(string excelConStr)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection excelCreateCon = new OleDbConnection(excelConStr))
        {
            OleDbCommand excelCreateCmd = new OleDbCommand();
            excelCreateCmd.Connection = excelCreateCon

            ...
```

Using debug, excelConStr returns

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=\\server\\Projects\\Project1\\Test.xls; Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes; MultipleActiveResultSets=True\";"

excelCreateCmd.Connection.DataSource returns "\\server\\Projects\\Project1\\Test.xls"
```

which looks fine. However, it is giving me the following error: `'C:\server\Projects\Project1\Test.xls' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.`

Any suggestion to resolve this issue? Please Experts!!
(Note: There is no PERMISSON problem)

Comment: Well, is it a valid path? - Apart from that, a UNC path will start with a double, not a single slash.

Comment: @flq, as you can see, every string value, I set double slash.. I don't have any single slash value. it just returns C:\server --- .. I don't know why

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Double slash because you have to escape the slash - so a double-slash is \\\\ .

Comment: @flq, ohhh so pathCreate should return "\\\\server\\Projects\\Project1\\Test.xls"? Let me test out.

Comment: @flq, nope. it does not work. still returning 'C;\server\...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For network i think you need not \server but \\server, not?

Comment: what do you mean? 'pathCreate' has to be '\server'? not '\\server'?

Comment: No, i mean that you should use double slesh for neteork psth. Do you should put slesh  4 times as @flq described. Probably, becsuse your path dtsrt from single slesh, .Net handle it as path from the root, and add c: